# Generic browser access to IP ICSEE

Tags: firefox, ip, chinese

[ICSEE Camera on ebay](https://t.ly/SAn4)
Is there anyway to access the video on this camera without having that infernal ActiveX installed on my computer? I am strictly a Linux user, so I have to fire up a windows virtual machine to be able to access it from a browser.

I have a lot of these cheap ip cameras and I am able to secure them behind my home network creating virtual hosts for them on apache servers which are internet accessible. I was hoping to do that for this one too.
Here is an example of how one can access the low res video stream on an amcrest camera. "http://usrname:password@ip-address:80/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi?channel=1&subtype=1"  I was hoping there was something like that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Bib this is a an IP camera not a usb camera.